# Align max-width aligned right with max-width margin auto in css

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin

I am trying to achieve the following align effect between divs.

[image]

The blue box has to occupy the same width as the red boxes, but also the auto margin-right.
This way, if the screen is resized reds and blues will be always aligned.

Is there any way to achieve that in CSS?

I tried to apply margin-left on the blue, also display a grid with grid-template-column: auto 1fr auto; but seems like it is not working because I can't get the auto margin.

I am adding a codepen to help people to see the problem and test.

https://codepen.io/Raikish/pen/BaWoexV

```html
<div class="centered red"></div>
<div class="centered red"></div>
<div class="right blue"></div>
```

```css
.centered {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1000px
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height : 200px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
.right {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 250px);
  max-width: 1000px
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you set the size to be half the viewport size (`50vw`) + half the element size (=`250px`), you'll get the correct max-width for the `.right` element.
After that, you can simply use `margin-left: auto` for that element just as you used it for the `.centered` element.

https://codepen.io/thatkookooguy/pen/bGqVPEJ

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --width: 500px;
  --half-width: calc(var(--width) / 2);
  --height: 50px;
}

.centered {
  max-width: var(--width);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.right {
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: calc(50vw + var(--half-width));
}

.shared {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: var(--height);
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="shared centered red"></div>
<div class="shared centered red"></div>
<div class="shared right blue"></div>
```